# Flutter Jinkins issue

Tags: android, flutter, jenkins

C:\ProgramData\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\new_application>flutter build apk --debug

Building with sound null safety

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
'attrib' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter_windows_3.7.12-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 901
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             34.6s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE